# Filling region between curve and x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to simply fill the area under the curve of a plot in Python using MatPlotLib.

Here is my SSCCE:

```
import json
import pprint
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,863,969,978,957,764,767,1009,1895,980,791]
x = np.arange(len(y))


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.fill(x, y)

plt.savefig('picForWeb.png')
plt.show()
```

The attached picture shows the output produced.[image: output of fill]

Does anyone know why Python is not filling the entire area in between the x-axis and the curve?

I've done Google and StackOverflow searches, but could not find a similar example.  Intuitively it seems that it should fill the entire area under the curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use the fill_between function for these kinds of plots. Try something like this instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,863,969,978,957,764,767,1009,1895,980,791]
x = np.arange(len(y))

fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1,1); 
ax1.fill_between(x, 0, y)
plt.show()
```

See more examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html).

Comment: your example works perfectly.  Its still unclear to me why the fill function has the behavior seen in the attached picture, but hey if fill_between works, it works!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use this on a `pd.DataFrame` use this:

```
df.abs().interpolate().plot.area(grid=1, linewidth=0.5)
```

`interpolate()` is optional.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`plt.fill` assumes that you have a closed shape to fill - interestingly if you add a final 0 to your data you get a much more sensible looking plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,863,969,978,957,764,767,1009,1895,980,791,0]
x = np.arange(len(y))


fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
ax2.fill(x, y)

plt.savefig('picForWeb.png')
plt.show()
```

Results in:
[image: Closed Plot]

Hope this helps to explain your odd plot.

Comment: I see now, that makes sense.  So the 'fill function' is for filling the region within closed polygons.  On the other hand, the 'fill_between' function is for the area between curves. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I am curious if there is no simpler way to do this than creating extra lists which have to be the length of your data.This feature is high in demand.